# How may I calculate the difference between Registered DateTime and DateTime.now in a gridview?

Tags: asp.net, datetime, gridview

I want to calculate the difference between Registered DateTime(is in a database) and `DateTime.now` in a `gridview`, But get an error. How may I calculate the difference between those times? When I use `(Eval("RegDtTime")-DateTime.Now`, get this error: `operator '-' is not defined for types 'Object' and 'Date'.` How should I calculate the difference?

```
     <asp:GridView
        ID="GridView1"

        runat="server" 
        AllowSorting="True" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataKeyNames="ID" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" 
                HeaderText="ID" 
                ReadOnly="True" 
                SortExpression="ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="RegDtTime" 
                HeaderText="RegDtTime" 
                SortExpression="RegDtTime" />
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" 
                            runat="server" 
                            onclick="LinkButton1_Click" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("ID") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        RegDateTime:
                        <asp:Label ID="Label3" 
                            runat="server"                                                             
                            Text='<%# Bind("RegDtTime") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        DateTimeNow:
                        <asp:Label ID="Label4" 
                            runat="server"                                 
                            Text='<%# DateTime.Now %>'></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        Passed:
                        <asp:Label ID="Label5" 
                            runat="server"                                                                                             
                            Text='<%# (Eval("RegDtTime")-DateTime.Now %>'></asp:Label>
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: update error message.

Comment: operator '-' is not defined for types 'Object' and 'Date'.

Comment: yep, that explains you right? `Eval` is returning an `object`. So you need to  `cast` it to `DateTime`.

Comment: So how is it possible to calculate them?

Comment: Should I use another way? Isn't it completely possible to calculate the difference between them?

Comment: Thanks Bharad waj. `(Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("LastDateTime"))- (DateTime.Now))` is what I want. But now I don't know how to convert it to just minutes.

Comment: Use the `.TotalMinutes` property on the result of the subtraction. Like this: `(Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("LastDateTime"))- (DateTime.Now)).TotalMinutes`

Comment: Try to use DateDiff function